# Jquery Call onchange function on dynamically created dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, onchange, dropdown

How to Call onchange function on dynamically created dropdown. Code is like below :
HTML Code :

```
<img id="addColumn" src="images/icons/panel_add.gif" alt="Add Column" onclick="addColumnDynamically('q_123_456_789')"/>
<div class = "q_123_456_789"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function addColumnDynamically(currentObjId){
maxRepeatedColumnSeq = maxRepeatedColumnSeq+1;
var dropDownIdStr = currentObjId;
dropDownIdStr = dropDownIdStr.substring(dropDownIdStr.indexOf("_") + 1);;
dropDownIdStr = "q_drop_"+dropDownIdStr+"_"+maxRepeatedColumnSeq;
alert("idStr........"+dropDownIdStr);
$("."+currentObjId).append('<div class="Content22">\
        <br>\
        <input class="input numberElement" type="text" style="width: 25%" id='+currentObjId+"_"+maxRepeatedColumnSeq+'>\
        <select class="selectStyle1" style="width: 25%" id='+dropDownIdStr+'<option value=""></option><option value=""></option><option value="Hours">Hours</option><option value="Days">Days</option><option value="Weeks">Weeks</option><option value="Months">Months</option><option value="Years">Years</option> >\
        <img src="images/icons/panel_remove.gif" onclick="removeColumn(this)">\
        <br>\
    </div>');
 $('#'+currentObjId+"_"+maxRepeatedColumnSeq).on('blur', function () {
alert("Hiii....");
});
alert("Hiii.."+dropDownIdStr);
$('#'+dropDownIdStr).on('change', function () {
alert("getElementById...."+document.getElementById(dropDownIdStr));
});
}
```

onblur function is calling but onchange is not calling. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code: You missed the closing ">" and the closing `"</select>"`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '#addColumn', function(evt){ addColumnDynamically('q_123_456_789')} );
  
})

function addColumnDynamically(currentObjId){
var maxRepeatedColumnSeq = maxRepeatedColumnSeq+1;
var dropDownIdStr = currentObjId;
dropDownIdStr = dropDownIdStr.substring(dropDownIdStr.indexOf("_") + 1);;
dropDownIdStr = "q_drop_"+dropDownIdStr+"_"+maxRepeatedColumnSeq;
alert("idStr........"+dropDownIdStr);
$("."+currentObjId).append('<div class="Content22">\
        <br>\
        <input class="input numberElement" type="text" style="width: 25%" id='+currentObjId+"_"+maxRepeatedColumnSeq+'>\
        <select class="selectStyle1" style="width: 25%" id='+dropDownIdStr+'><option value=""></option><option value=""></option><option value="Hours">Hours</option><option value="Days">Days</option><option value="Weeks">Weeks</option><option value="Months">Months</option><option value="Years">Years</option></select>\
        <img src="images/icons/panel_remove.gif" onclick="removeColumn(this)">\
        <br>\
    </div>');

alert("Hiii.."+dropDownIdStr);
$('#'+dropDownIdStr).on('change', function () {
alert("getElementById...."+document.getElementById(dropDownIdStr));
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code change onchange to change! Also, because the element is dynamically created is better to use:

```
$(document).on(event, element, handler)
```

In your case:

```
$(document).on('change', '#'+dropDownIdStr, function () {
alert("getElementById...."+document.getElementById(dropDownIdStr));
});
```

Comment: <select class="selectStyle1" style="width: 25%" id='+dropDownIdStr+' is missing the ">" and  I don't see the closing </select>

Comment: I closed the select tag after  option tag like   ... >Years</option> >\

Answer (score 0):

The event is 'change', not 'onchange'.

```
$('#' + dropDownIdStr).on('change', function () {
    alert("getElementById...." + document.getElementById(dropDownIdStr));
});
```